# Are questions related to specific malware on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am new to this site. Can I ask questions specific to a given malware in Android here?

For example,

1. How did so and so malware infect my phone?
2. What steps should I take to protect my phone/to remove the malware?
3. Because of so and so, the commonly given solution won't work in my case. What should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The description of Android Enthusiasts on the [tour page](https://android.stackexchange.com/tour) is that Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange is *a question and answer site for **users** of the Android operating system.*

Furthermore, on the related [help page](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) it is said that:

> If your question generally covers...
>
> - Using your Android device
> - Using a particular app on your Android device
> - Trying to solve **an error or other issue** in using your Android device
>
> then this is the right place to ask.

A malware that operates on Android is surely an issue for **end-users** of Android. So it is welcome on Android.SE if you ask for precautions or support against.